# Is there a way to use a named function with Hapi validation?

Tags: validation, hapi.js

http://hapijs.com/tutorials/validation

I'd like to pass a function in to my validation block that checks for the presence of `v` as a source and confirms that `account`, `profile` and `ipAddress` are present. The docs say this is possible but don't have an example of using a function var to do it.

When I start up my API I get: `Error: Invalid schema content: (account)`

How can I use a named function to do validation in Hapi?

Code:

```
  var validateQueryString;

  validateQueryString = function(value, options, next) {
    console.dir({
      value: value,
      options: options
    });

    // do some validation here 

    return next(null, value);
  };

  routes.push({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/export/{source}/{start}/{end?}',
    config: {
      validate: {
        query: {
          account: validateQueryString,
          profile: validateQueryString,
          ipAddress: validateQueryString
        },
        params: {
          source: joi.string().valid(['a', 'v', 't']),
          start: joi.string().regex(utcDateTimeRegex),
          end: joi.string().regex(utcDateTimeRegex)
        }
      }
    },
    handler: function(apiRequest, apiReply) {}
  });
```

Tried other ways of calling this like:

```
account: function(value, options, next) {
  return validateQueryString(value, options, next); }
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a single function to handle both at the same time.

Typically, the method for the full 'list' of query parameter.  Here is a bit of code to illustrate:

```
function validateQuery(value, options, next){
  console.log( 'validating query elements');
  for (var k in value) {
    console.log( k, '=', value[k]);
  }
  next(new Error(null, value);
}
```

And you set it as follow:

```
routes.push({
    ...
    validate: {
      query: validateQuery,
      params: ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

Now, let's assume you hit `http://server/myroute?a=1&b=2&c=3`, you will get the following output:

```
validating query elements
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

If you want to throw an error, you have to call `next()` as follow:

```
next( new Error('some is wrong'), value );
```

So the 'proper' way is to have a method for query and params, it seems.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend what you are doing is out of bounds of `Joi`'s intent.  `Joi` is targetted for schema validation against a JS object.  What you want is runtime validation against rules that exist outside of the schema itself.  `Hapi` has something built for this called [server method](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/server-methods).  Leveraging server methods, you can apply your business validations there while separating the concerns of input model and output model shape validation through `Joi`.